# Tabla de Sinónimos de etiqueta no funciona correctamente

Tags: bug, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

La tabla donde se muestran los Sinónimos de etiqueta del sitio en español no está funcionando correctamente. Si entran [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) y le pican a la columna *Creado*, en teoría debería ordenar ASC o DESC los Sinónimos de etiquetas por su fecha de creación, cosa que no ocurre así.

No quiero pensar que otras tablas tengan este comportamiento pero voy a estar checándolas por si acaso.

Esto ya se verificó en el sitio Meta General y allá si funciona correctamente: posiblemente sea por el formato de fecha.

Comment: igual hay que postearlo en meta general.. el bug es generico, aca no lo ven los devs...

Comment: @gbianchi Al parecer el problema solo puede reproducirse en SOes. Lo testeé en SO, pt.SO y ja.SO y lo ordenan correctamente.

Comment: Igual es un bug de la red, se postea en meta..

Comment: Reportado hace más de tres años en el Meta grande: [Ordering by columns not working on many columns in Tag Synonyms page of SOes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356516/209901). Nunca hubo reacción

Comment: a lo mejor no te hicieron  caso por que no eres moderador y ese bug solo afecta al 0.001% de los usuarios y no es nada...

Comment: @fedorqui ¿realmente corresponde la etiqueta que agregaste? Lo pregunto porque veo que hace referencia a la creación o discusión acerca de etiquetas, no a la "visualización", por decirlo de algún modo.

Comment: @padaleiana nop es como lo dices ... en el etiqueta dice _Para la discusión, solicitud, o preguntas generales pidiendo soporte sobre la creación de sinónimos de etiquetas._

Comment: da la cadualidad que el registro de la creacion de la etiqueta es lo que proboca esa fecha que despues no se puede ordenar por la columna _creado_ ...

Comment: Ya hubo reacción... en la pregunta mencionada por fedorqui el día de "ayer",  recién agregaron la etiqueta `status-review`.

Comment: @Rubén yo la comente para reflotarla y ver si llamaba la atencion ...

Comment: Los comentarios no reflotan preguntas, sólo las ediciones, algunas acciones de moderación que afecten el estado de la pregunta y el publicar una respuesta. P.D. Yo reporté la pregunta a los moderadores de MSE, pero no puedo aseguar que ello haya sido lo que los llevó a asignar la etiqueta mencionada en mi comentario anterior. Un factor que seguramente ha sido importante es la puntación que tiene; se ha incrementado recientemente.

Comment: a bueno entonces debe ser pura coincidencia que lo hayan visto ahora ...

Comment: ya vamos pa casi un mes ... y no se ha dicho mas nada XD